# Is a metric tensor a norm of the tangent space?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, tangent-spaces

In a (pseudo-) Riemannian manifold, we have a metric tensor defined on each point in the manifold. I.e. a tensor field.

With this metric tensor we can define also a metric on the manifold by integrating over the metric tensor along a curve, making the manifold a metric space.

However, generally the manifold is not  necessarily a normed space, since a norm induces a metric but a metric not a norm.

**However, when we look at the tangent space at each point in the manifold, is it correct to say that the metric tensor $g$ is a norm of a vector $v$ on that tangent space, if we take the metric tensor of $v$ with itself ($g(v,v)$)?**

Comment: A Riemannian metric $g$ assigns to each tangent space $T_pM$ an inner product $g_p$; this inner product in turn induces both a norm and a metric on the tangent space, yes. Note that the norm of a vector $v$ in $T_pM$  is not $g_p(v,v)$ but the square root of that. If you deal with pseudo-Riemannian metrics, you no longer get a norm.

Comment: It's not that a manifold is **not necessarily** a normed space - it **can't** be a normed space because it has no linear structure. The concept of a norm makes sense only on a vector space and a manifold doesn't come with a vector space structure.

Comment: @levap you can add a vector space structure though, right. For example, $R^2$ is a manifold that admits a vector space structure

Comment: @symplectomorphic doesn't a Lorentzian manifold have a norm defined on its tangent spaces?

Comment: @Programmer2134: Indeed, $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a natural structure of both a vector space and a smooth manifold but this is the only case...

Comment: No, a Lorentzian manifold does not have a norm on tangent spaces, at least not in the strict and typical sense, which requires that the norm take nonnegative real values. You might find physicists or experts saying "norm" in that context, but they mean it only by analogy to the Riemannian setting. If you restrict to a spacelike subspace, though, you can talk about a norm.

Comment: Also, to respond to your confusion regarding levap's point: a generic Riemannian manifold $M$ isn't normed (because it's not even a vector space) but each tangent space $T_pM$ (which *is* a vector space) inherits a norm from the inner product $g_p$. You are confusing the norm in each tangent space with a norm on the manifold itself: the latter doesn't exist.

Comment: I was not confusing those two, I was simply stating that a manifold can be a vector space, which is at least teue for $R^d$. I assume there are more possibilities, but I'm not sure. But thank you, yes the point about the lorentzian "norm" is clear now.

Comment: "With this metric tensor we can define also a metric on the manifold by integrating over the metric tensor along a curve, making the manifold a metric space."  -   @user56834 Can you give some reference from where I can get a metric on Pseudo-Riemannian manifold, not only on tangent spaces?

Comment: @user56834 $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a very particular manifold. Obviously, compact manifolds are compact, thus cannot have a normed space structure. For open manifolds, some can have a vector space structure but this make them diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, and if the metric induces a normed structure, then they are flat, so they are basically just $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the euclidean structure.